# How do I show a div on scroll with a fadeout after a period of time? Want to use a fadein/fadeout effect with no loop

Tags: jquery, loops, fadein, fadeout

I want a div (a menu) to appear when the users scrolls, then fadeout after a brief time so it does not interfere with the reading, then appear again if the user scrolls. So far, the following code does the job, but I want a fadein effect when the div appears.

CSS

```
.onscrollbutton {
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".onscrollbutton").css("display","block").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
    });
</script>
```

Erasing the CSS and changing the jQuery code to this results in a fadein/fadeout loop, even if the user does not scroll:

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".onscrollbutton").fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
    });
</script>
```

How can I achieve the first effect, but with a smooth transition?

Comment: Sorry, I want the div (a menu) to appear every time the user scrolls. In case the user does not scroll for 5 seconds, the div fades out so it does not interfere with the user's reading. I will edit my question. The thing is the loop on the second code happens even if the user does not scroll.

Comment: Did you wrap that script in a ready? $(function(){}); I ask this only because it is possible that the page length is so long that is creates a scroll bar and triggers the script.

Answer (score 0):

`fadeOut` is causing the scroll event to trigger because it is basically removing the height of the `.onscrollbutton` element. Try absolute positioning the element and it should work. Worked for me.

Comment: I get the     $(".onscrollbutton").css("display","block").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow") code to work, but not the .fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow") one, even if I wrap it in a ready function or a window load one; or if used a fixed position or an absolute one. As soon as I scroll, the function will start looping.